# Bay tree can't seem to do well

Tags: bugs, blight

Basically I have a bay tree in a pot and it will sprout new leaves but soon afterwards, (some weeks/months) the leaves will die and go brown. See attached photo. It gets ample sun. I have tried pruning it and keep up regular insect treatments. I am currently in winter in Australia when this photo is taken.

[image: Bay Tree several years old, Winter Southern Hemisphere]

Comment: How long have you had the plant? Is that tall stick or stem without leaves  in the image part of it? What soil is it potted into?

Comment: I would say I've had the plant 1.5 years. It's potted in potting mix. That is one of the stem also which has similar foliage at the top.